# How To use ANDWF in Microchip PIC18fxxxx Assembly Language

Tags: microcontroller, pic, assembly, code

ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE MPLAB PIC18f2550

I am trying to "AND" 2 Variables "If Variable_1 = 0 AND Variable_2 = 1 then"
"DO WHAT IS NEEDED."   "End If"

This **below** makes no sense used as a "AND" Logic Function.
Will the above STATEMENT work using ANDWF or ANDLW? Do I need to ANDWF each Variable separately, or is it possible to use something else?

ANDWF f , d     Logic AND between the content of W register with the content of a file register 'f'. If d is 0 the result is stored in the W register, if d is 1 the result is stored back to the file register 'f'.
Operation: (W).AND. (f) ® destination
Description: AND the W register with register 'f'. If 'd' is 0 the result is stored in the W register. If 'd' is 1 the result is stored back in register 'f'.

I have read the data-sheet PIC18f2550 and the PIC18 Family
Reference Manual and Looked All over the internet and Stackexchange. 
I simply have not found an understandable answer. If the "ANDWF & ANDLW" are truly "AND" Functions

ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE MPLAB PIC18f2550

Answer (score 1):

The `IF`, `AND`, `THEN` and `END IF` in your code are all statements affecting program flow, not mathematical operators.

The PIC18F2550 has an instruction `CPFSEQ` (compare w to f, skip next instruction if equal) which can be used to implement the `AND` function in your example, like this:-

```
_if:
  MOVLW  0
  CPFSEQ Variable_1  ; IF Variable_1 = 0  
  GOTO   _endif      
  MOVLW  1
  CPFSEQ Variable_2  ; AND variable_2 = 1 
  GOTO   _endif      
  .
  .                  ; THEN do what is needed       
  .
_endif:
```

Note: this code just shows the principle, and may not be the most efficient (eg. using `TSTFSZ Variable_1` and `BRA _endif` would be faster and more compact).

Comment: After Working with the CPFSEQ I found out my question was actually easier than the question I needed to ask! The real problem turned out to be an AND OR problem.

Answer (score 0):

They're bit-wise AND instructions whereas if I'm reading your question correctly you're expecting a logical AND.

In these bit-wise AND instructions, each of the 8 bits of one operand are individually AND-ed with the appropriate bits of the other operand and the result is stored wherever specified.

So for example if your W register contains 0x23 and you execute a ANDLW 0x12 you will end up with 0x02 in W.

```
0x23   == 0b00100011  
0x12   == 0b00010010  
AND-ed == 0b00000010
```

Comment: So basically it is not a Logical AND....

Comment: Each individual bit gets a Logical AND, so if you feed those instructions appropriate operands you can make them look and act like logical ANDs...

Answer (score 0):

After Working with the CPFSEQ I found out my question was
 actually easier than the question I needed to ask!

The real problem turned out to be a combination AND OR  problem.

If var_1 = 0  AND  var_2 = 0  then  GOTO Loop..... If var_1 > 0 OR var_2 > 1 then GOTO Continue.

May not be the most efficient but it does work.

Main:

MOVLW    b'00000000'

```
 MOVWF    RxCount              ;Start Count at Zero
```

Loop:

MOVLW    b'00000000'  .....Set RxRegister to Zero   Normally changes in

Program Routine.

MOVWF    RxRegister

nop                                  ....;Added because the next MOVWF had a

number > 0, didn't work right     .

MOVLW  b'00000000'

CPFSGT  RxCount  ....; if RxCount = Zero  goto "If_Or_And" OR else 
GOTO Continue

GOTO      If_Or_And

Continue

```
INCF       RxCount

CALL      Other_Routines      ;Get RxRegister Data

        GOTO     Loop
```

If_Or_And:

```
TSTFSZ  RxRegister            ;if RxRegister > Zero then GOTO Continue: 

GOTO    Continue              ;if RxRegister = Zero then GOTO Loop: 

GOTO    Loop
```